# Odoo bind grid to Parent/Child tables

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to bind odoo grid to multiple tables in odoo form ?

I have Order and OrderLine, i want to display multiple orders and related lines in same grid, and the grid to be editable and save any changes.

Comment: **Have you tried One2many  field?**